# Notificação pela conta do usuário logado

Tags: android, notificação

Gostaria de saber como posso mandar uma notificação para um usuário logado no meu app. Por exemplo, que esteja logado com a conta: caio@gmail.com

Vi alguns exemplos como: `mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());`
mas não entendi como manipular esse `id`, se colocaria o email.

Provável que eu use o Firebase para cadastrar os usuários.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Caio!

1 - Sobre o exemplo do código da sua pergunta:

```
mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
```

o `id` ao qual você se refere é apenas um identificador interno para caso você queira atualizar sua notificação em outro momento. Esse tipo de notificação é um recurso disponibilizado pelo `SDK` do `Android`.

2 - Caso você queira que o seu app seja capaz de receber mensagens vindas diretamente do servidor (como solicitações de amizades, de curtidas e etc.), você pode utilizar o *Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)*, por exemplo.

3 - Quando você configurar seu app para finalmente receber as mensagens do *FCM*, você poderá utilizar a `API` nativa do `Android` de notificação (citada acima) para mostrar ao usuário que um evento ocorreu.

Acesse https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?hl=pt-br e veja como configurar seu app.

Espero que isso te ajude!

Comment: Eu gostaria de quando o usuário (x) fizesse uma transação que salvasse no database, pegaria os dados inseridos e mandaria uma notificação pro usuário (y). A ideia é fazer um app de aluguel de áreas de lazer, quando o usuário(x) comprasse a diária da área o usuário(y) seria notificado.

Comment: @CaioCavallari, para isso você precisará usar o _Cloud Functions_ e acionar evento no `database`